# Format list of IP addresses using sed adding subnet mask if necessary

Tags: bash, sed

I have a list of IP addresses like that:

```
208.69.112.145
54.230.228.48
104.21.75.86/31
104.16.139.76
172.67.210.123
104.21.54.226/31
45.146.81.248/31
205.251.219.56/30
```

It needs to be converted to this format:

```
route 208.69.112.145/32 reject;
route 54.230.228.48/32 reject;
route 104.21.75.86/31 reject;
route 104.16.139.76/32 reject;
route 172.67.210.123/32 reject;
route 104.21.54.226/31 reject;
route 45.146.81.248/31 reject;
route 205.251.219.56/30 reject;
```

So every address should start with `route`  and end with  `reject;`

Except for the lines that don't have a subnet mask, for those lines `/32 reject;` should be added instead.

This works, but it adds `/32` to every line:

`cat /ip.lst | sed 's_.*_route &/32 reject;_' > /ip.txt`

Comment: Add a second substitution step that strips the superfluous netmask. Or, use two substitutions for the two variants with and without netmask.

Answer (score 3):

Add `32` only if it's missing.

```
sed '\_/[0-9][0-9]_!s_$_/32_; s_.*_route & reject;_'
```

Hope you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's~^~route ~; s~\.[0-9]+$~&/32~; s~$~ reject;~' file

route 208.69.112.145/32 reject;
route 54.230.228.48/32 reject;
route 104.21.75.86/31 reject;
route 104.16.139.76/32 reject;
route 172.67.210.123/32 reject;
route 104.21.54.226/31 reject;
route 45.146.81.248/31 reject;
route 205.251.219.56/30 reject;
```

Or this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F/ '{print "route", $0 (NF==2 ? "" : "/32"), "reject;"}' file

route 208.69.112.145/32 reject;
route 54.230.228.48/32 reject;
route 104.21.75.86/31 reject;
route 104.16.139.76/32 reject;
route 172.67.210.123/32 reject;
route 104.21.54.226/31 reject;
route 45.146.81.248/31 reject;
route 205.251.219.56/30 reject;
```